# INSERT through SELECT data from another table with additional manual data PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert

I am trying to insert the data from the other table, It is not working I read all the threads on StackOverflow and w3school but based on it my SQL not working.
I am trying to insert the all data one by one which available in table `pincode` WHERE `state = US`
I think my code is right but it not inserting the data.  I am selecting some around three cols from `pincode table` and others for I manually assign the parameter in execute array in PHP

Please help, how I insert the data from `pincode` to `table_alloted`.

Please help..

table = pincode

| ID | pin_code | district | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | distname1 | US |
| 2 | 123457 | distname2 | US |
| 3 | 123458 | distname3 | US |
| 4 | 123459 | distname4 | US |

table = table_alloted

| ID | pin_code | district | state | tech_id | insert_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | distname1 | US | ts12563 | 17-06-2021 |
| 2 | 123457 | distname2 | US | ts12563 | 17-06-2021 |
| 3 | 123458 | distname3 | US | ts12563 | 17-06-2021 |
| 4 | 123459 | distname4 | US | ts12563 | 17-06-2021 |

Code:

```
$sqlInsert= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `table_alloted` (`tech_id `, `insert_dt`, `pin_code`, `district`, `state`) VALUES(:tech_id, :my_date, (SELECT `pin_code`, `district`, `state` FROM `pincode` WHERE `state` = :state)");
$sqlInsert->execute(array(
  ':tech_id' => 'ts12563',
  ':my_date' => date('d-m-Y'),
  ':state' => 'US'
));
```

Comment: Insert into my_table (...) SELECT :tech_id, etc...

Comment: Maybe use `$conn->getPdo();` and this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below query

```
INSERT INTO `table_alloted` (`tech_id `, `insert_dt`, `pin_code`, `district`, `state`)
SELECT :tech_id, :my_date, `pin_code`, `district`, `state` FROM `pincode` WHERE `state` = :state
```

I am not sure about your syntax in PHP but in database the above query will work.

Answer (score 2):

Below PHP code according to @Amit Verma query:

```
//Prepare statement
$sqlInsert = $con->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO `table_alloted` (`tech_id`, `insert_dt`, `pin_code`, `district`, `state`) 
    SELECT :tech_id, :my_date, `pin_code`, `district`, `state` FROM `pincode` WHERE `state` = :state"
);
//Execute insert
$sqlInsert->execute([
    ":tech_id" => "ts12563",
    ":my_date" => date("Y-m-d"),
    ":state" => "US",
]);
//Check result
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table_alloted`;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($rows);
```

[PHP & MySQL online playground](https://phpize.online/?phpses=5446419e3801d0f4d3aa0777c7e35150&sqlses=167b9d6d065401e7feea2660d62eb2a6&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)